# Matlab on Ubuntu: Unable to read file

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I am trying to run a MATLAB program on my computer running Ubuntu 12.04. Then when it runs to the code

```
load('data\sparse_combinations\Tw.mat', 'Tw')
```

MATLAB will report this error

> ```
> Error using load
> Unable to read file 'data\sparse_combinations\Tw.mat': no sucn file or directory
> ```

But when I enter the directory 'sparse_combinations', then run the code

```
 load('Tw.mat')
```

it works well.

Can you help me find the reason?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `load('data/sparse_combinations/Tw.mat', 'Tw')`. In linux path separator is `/`.

Comment: Yes, that's just the key to my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870222/matlab-on-ubuntu-unable-to-read-file#comment33112557_21870222) the problem is the usage of the wrong path seperator.

A good and general fix for this type of issue would be the use of [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) - this command takes care of the issues of path seperation and platforms for you.

```
load( fullfile('data','sparse_combinations','Tw.mat'), 'Tw')
```

will work both on windows machines as well as Linux/Unix ones. **No need to change code** when porting to other platforms!

Comment: Yeah, that's really a good idea! Thank you very sincerely!